# Get 2 numbers from user and display range between those two nos

Tags: javascript

Get 2 numbers from the user and display range between those two nos. Below is my code:

```
  var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
  var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
  var i = num1; 
  while (i < 10) {
    i++;
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to display sequence of the numbers? Ex: I typed *2 and 7* respectivly then it should display `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

Answer (score 1):

Will add an extra check to validate User's entered values:)

```js
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));

if (ValidateInputs(num1) && ValidateInputs(num2)) {
    var i = num1;
    while (i <= num2) {
        console.log(i)
        i++;
    }
} else {
    alert("Invalid Inputs")
}

function ValidateInputs(numb) {
    if (numb >= 1 && numb <= 10) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the while loop and the condition in the loop is wrong

```js
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
var i = num1;
while (i <= num2) {
  console.log(i)
  i++;

}
```

Comment: Please,Try to validate the negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));

for(i=num1;i<=num2;i++) {
    document.write(i+"<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Try to put validation for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help you

```
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10"));

if(num1 >=1 && num1 <=10) && (num1 >=1 && num1 <=10){
   var i = num1;
   while (i < num2) {
     console.log(i++);   // Please print or write to a document 
   }
}
else{
   console.log("Enter a valid number between 1 and 10")
}

>> Enter a number 1 to 10  1
>> Enter a number 1 to 10  10
>>> 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Please if you want to include the number entered please do include `<=` so it goes until the last number.

```
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10"));
if(num1 >=1 && num1 <=10) && (num1 >=1 && num1 <=10){
    var i = num1;
    while (i <= num2) {
      console.log(i)
      i++;   // Please print or write to a document 
    }
}
else{
   console.log("Enter a valid number between 1 and 10")
}

>> Enter a number 1 to 10  1
>> Enter a number 1 to 10  10
>>> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Please remove the `if` and `else` if you want the code to work for any numbers without a restriction

Comment: Please,Try to validate the negative numbers

Comment: It works for negative numbers as well @ShivaniPatel

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate the range at once you can do that with help of [Array.prototype.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys):

```js
var num1 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));
var num2 = Number(prompt("Enter a number 1 to 10:"));

const range = [...Array(num2 - 1).keys()].slice(num1).map(n => n + 1);

alert(range)
```